# Deploying classic ASP application on IIS through Docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, asp-classic

I want to deploy my legacy classic asp application on IIS through docker.I am able to create image and i am able to run the image. Everything works well,but when i tried hit the IP Address ,it is not working.

I  followed below steps.
1.I used below Docker file and my application placed in share folder.
2.I ran the docker file using following power shell command:

Docker file:

```
#escape=`
FROM microsoft/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2016
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-ASP

COPY ./share/ClassicAspApp.zip

RUN Expand-Archive -Path ClassicAspApp.zip -DestinationPath C:\ClassicAspApp; `
    Remove-Item ClassicAspApp.zip

RUN Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'; `
    New-Website -Name web-app -Port 80 -PhysicalPath C:\ClassicAspApp

Shell Command :
docker image build `
  -t sixeyed/w2k3-classic-asp `
  -f .\docker\classic-asp\Dockerfile .   #1.1

docker container run -d sixeyed/w2k3-classic-asp
```

At last i ran the docker container inspect given Container id .then it shows the all the details about the container,in that i found ip address,when i hit the ip address in the browser. Its not displaying my site.

Comment: Have you checked container logs? `docker logs -f {container id}`

Comment: Checked the logs but there is no logs captured. The file size is 0kb. is it related to any proxy settings ?

Comment: C# , .net and asp.net have nothing to do with classic asp. Have you left some info out or put too much info in?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing port mapping while run the container: Try like this

```
docker run -d -p 8081:80 sixeyed/w2k3-classic-asp
```

And then try accessing your website at `http://localhost:8081`

Note 8081 is any random port you can even map port 80 on your machine to port 80 of the container

Comment: Great thank you so much,it works for me.Could you tell me how to test database connection.I have one page which connects to SQL and display the details.how to install drivers in container to talk to database. i have sql server database but container doesnt have sql server native client 11.please help me out